# Looking for a Node.js client for Message Hub

Tags: message-hub

I'm creating an application using Node.js and I'm interested in a Message Hub client or library.

Is there an official Node.js client for Message Hub?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's one and is open source. You can find it at https://github.com/ibm-messaging/message-hub-rest